# Delete a link from Top header M2

Tags: magento2

[image]I installed a new template and it contain a link **contact Us** . I want to delete it from top header how to proceed . this is the content of my default.xml of the theme

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_head" template="html/head.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="porto_newsletter_popup" template="subscribe_popup.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_notice" template="html/custom_notice.phtml" after="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_sidebar_sticky" template="html/sidebar_sticky.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_header" template="html/header.phtml" before="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Form\Login" name="header_customer_form_login" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/login_popup" template="Smartwave_Porto::html/login.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_block" template="html/header_custom_block.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/static_block" after="-"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="minicart" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="currency" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="skip_to_content" destination="porto_header"/>

    <move element="page.top" destination="page.wrapper" after="porto_header"/>

    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="1"/>

    <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_link" before="authorization-link-login" template="html/custom_link.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

so how to delete it and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Can you check if there is any static blocks added for that section? Or Try to disable the "custom_block"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are using the theme, they insert block statically, so We can done this by below ways:**

> Type 1: open the phtml and comment out that code

Path: `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/custom_link.phtml`

```
<?php
$porto_helper = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data');
?>
<!-- <li><a href="<?php echo $porto_helper->getBaseLinkUrl(); ?>contact"><?php echo __('Contact Us'); ?></a></li> -->
```

> Type 2: remove the block using XML (add below line in your `default.xml`)

```
<referenceBlock name="custom_link" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: you are welcome, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from your theme's settings panel > custom style (css)
insert this code :

```
.header.links{display:none !important;}
```

don't forget to flush cache
then check if it works.

Comment: i want just to delete contactez nous in top header

Comment: you can go to your admin panel and go to CONTENT -> BLOCKS 
from there you can find the header block and remove what you want to remove